# How to avoid :authenticity_token unpermitted params on create in Rails with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise in a Rails 6 app and running into an issue with `:authenticity_token` being an `Unpermitted parameter`. How do I create a new instance of `Audit`, allow the `authenticity_token` but not pass into `create`?

my AuditsController class:

```
class AuditsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :audits_params



  def show
    @audit = Audit.last
  end

  def create
    @audit = Audit.create(audits_params)
    byebug 
    if @audit.save 
      redirect_to audits_show_path(@audit)
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Unable to create audit"
    end
  end

  private 

  def audits_params 
    params.permit(:request_state, :time_modified, :request_license, :account, :customers_reason, :format)
  end

end
```

and on my `applicationController class`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :authenticate_user!  

end
```

Also using `rails_admin` but not sure if that matters.

Comment: if you've set up your new form canonically, you are likely just missing a require in your params.   `params.require(:audit).permit(:request_state, :time_modified, :request_license, :account, :customers_reason, :format) ` You also don't need the `before_action :audit_params`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue